# Set if &cp | set noocp | endif in the ~/.vimrc file

Tags: vim

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Vim 7.4

Setting in ~/.vimrc file

```
if &cp | set noocp | endif
```

I'm curious about the function of the phrase
What is &cp and what function is |?
I'm also curious about the function of if...endif

Sorry, I'm a beginner If you give me an answer, it will help me a lot

Comment: I believe `cp` stands for `compatible`. More info at `:help compatible`

Answer (score 3):

First, let's fix that nagging typo:

```
if &cp | set nocp | endif
```

Now we can talk…

The whole thing is a conditional:

```
if <expression that evaluates to 1 ("true")>
  <do something>
endif
```

See `:help 41.4`.

If you want to save space, you can put a sequence of commands on a single line, separated with `|`:

```
if <expression that evaluates to 1> | <do something> | endif
```

See `:help :bar`.

`&cp`, or `&compatible`, is an expression that evaluates to `1` (true in vimscript) if the `compatible` option is set and `0` (false) if it is disabled:

```
if &cp | <do something> | endif
```

See `:help 'compatible'` and `:help expr-option`

The statement between the `:if` and the `:else` is `set nocp`, which unsets `compatible`:

```
if &cp | set nocp | endif
```

So, that line tells Vim to check if `compatible` is set and, if yes, to unset it.

---

FWIW, `compatible` is automatically unset when Vim encounters a `vimrc` at an expected location so `&cp` is always going to be evaluated to `0` in your `~/.vimrc`, which, basically, makes that line useless outside of very specific use cases that you shouldn't encounter if you have to ask that question.

Comment: May be `set nocp`, not `set noocp`?

Comment: @hobo-mts What do you mean?

Comment: `@romainl`, I mean typo no*o*cp

Answer (score 0):

`&cp` -- value of Vim option `cp` (`:h 41.3`, `:h 'cp'`), `|` -- another command in same command line (`:h :bar`), `if ... endif` -- conditional expression (`:h :if`).